# R - convert from categorical to numeric for KNN

Tags: r, knn, r-caret, categorical-data

I'm trying to use the Caret package of R to use the KNN applied to the "abalone" database from UCI Machine Learning (link to the [data](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/abalone/abalone.data)). But it doesn't allow to use KNN when there's categorical values.
How do I convert the categorical values (in this database: `"M","F","I"`) to numeric values, such as `1,2,3`, respectively?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When data are read in via `read.table`, the data in the first column are factors. Then

```
data$iGender = as.integer(data$Gender)
```

would work. If they are character, a detour via factor is easiest:

```
data$iGender= as.integer(as.factor(data$Gender))
```

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to use `data[1]` instead of `$V1`.

Comment: This is a bad idea for unordered categorical variables.

Answer (score 16):

The first answer seems like a really bad idea. Coding `{"M","F","I"}` to `{1, 2, 3}` implies that `Infant = 3 * Male`, `Male = Female/2` and so on.

`KNN` via `caret` does allow categorical values as predictors if you use the formula methods. Otherwise you need to encode them as binary [dummy variables](http://topepo.github.io/caret/preprocess.html#dummy).

Also, showing your code and having a reproducible example would help a lot.

Max

Comment: Actually, this type of encoding is quite useful for tree based algorithm (e.g. xgboost) and is used in the LabelEncoder pre-processing library of scikit learn. I was just out looking to see if R had this type of functionality built in.

Comment: May I ask how to use the formula methods in `caret` to allow categorical variables? Can I directly throw a dataset `k = train(y~., method='knn', 
            trControl=train.control, preProcess=c('scale','center','pca'),
            data=data.frame(train))` with categorical variables?

Answer (score 1):

One of easiest way to use kNN algorithm in your dataset in which one of its feature is categorical : "M", "F" and "I" as you mentioned is as follows:
Just in your CVS or Excel file that your dataset exsits, go ahead in the right column and change M to 1 and F to 2 and I to 3. In this case you have discrete value in your dataset and you can easily use kNN algorithm using R.

Answer (score 0):

> You can simply read the file with stringsAsFactors = TRUE

Example

```
data_raw<-read.csv('...../credit-default.csv', stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
```

The stringasfactors will give a numerical replacement for the Char datatypes

Answer (score 0):

Try using knncat package in R, which converts categorical variables into numerical counterpart.

[Here's the link for the package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/knncat/knncat.pdf)