# No missing values are allows kNN in R

Tags: r, knn

I've data set of 45212 elements with 17 columns and i want to find the class label of last column using kNN algorithm, according to me everything is OK, but I always come up with error

```
"Error in knn(train = data_train, test = data_test, cl = data_train_labels,  : 
  no missing values are allowed"
```

here is my code

```
> data_train <-data[1:25000,]
> data_test <-data[25001:45212,]
> data_train_labels <- data[1:25000, 17]
> data_test_labels <- data[1:25000, 17]
> install.package("class")
> library(class)
> data_test_pred <- knn(train=data_train, test=data_test, cl=data_train_labels, k=10)
```

here is how my data set looks like:

```
age,job,marital,education,default,balance,housing,loan,contact,day,month,duration,campaign,pdays,previous,poutcome,y
58,management,married,tertiary,no,2143,yes,no,unknown,5,may,261,1,-1,0,unknown,no
44,technician,single,secondary,no,29,yes,no,unknown,5,may,151,1,-1,0,unknown,no
33,entrepreneur,married,secondary,no,2,yes,yes,unknown,5,may,76,1,-1,0,unknown,no
47,blue-collar,married,unknown,no,1506,yes,no,unknown,5,may,92,1,-1,0,unknown,no
33,unknown,single,unknown,no,1,no,no,unknown,5,may,198,1,-1,0,unknown,no
35,management,married,tertiary,no,231,yes,no,unknown,5,may,139,1,-1,0,unknown,no
28,management,single,tertiary,no,447,yes,yes,unknown,5,may,217,1,-1,0,unknown,no
42,entrepreneur,divorced,tertiary,yes,2,yes,no,unknown,5,may,380,1,-1,0,unknown,no
58,retired,married,primary,no,121,yes,no,unknown,5,may,50,1,-1,0,unknown,no
43,technician,single,secondary,no,593,yes,no,unknown,5,may,55,1,-1,0,unknown,no
41,admin.,divorced,secondary,no,270,yes,no,unknown,5,may,222,1,-1,0,unknown,no
```

Comment: Debug your code. Find where are missing values, and at what step you get them.

Comment: what values is compiler talking about ?
I don't find any missing values in my dataset

Comment: Either data_train, or data_test, or data_train_labels probably contain missing values

Comment: How did you check for missing values?  Could you try `length(complete.cases(data_train))` and the same with data_test and data_train_labels ?

Comment: BTW,  it is a different problem but you have a cut-and-paste error in the test_labels `data_test_labels <- data[1:25000, 17]` should be `data_test_labels <- data[25001:45212, 17]`

Comment: I edited the question and put a sample of my data set

Comment: i fixed that cut-and-paste mistake, but the same error is still there

Comment: I tested all the values using length(complete.cases(data_train)) and they are fine

Comment: Not 100% certain,  but I think that your problem is all of the categorical variables.  The knn documentation says that it computes Euclidean distance between points.  How can it do that with factors?

Comment: yes, i suspect that alphabetical values are causing the issues,
what should be done to those values in order to apply kNN algorithm

Comment: Take a look at [This SO Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30058362/r-convert-from-categorical-to-numeric-for-knn)  It may help.

Comment: Thanks, do you have any idea, after converting all columns to numeric values, will the above piece of code work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your problem is all of the factors in your data. The knn documentation says that it uses Euclidean distance, which does not make sense for factors.  Here is a possible solution if you really want to use knn. You can get a distance matrix between the points using `daisy` in the cluster package. There are several implementations of knn in R but I don't know of one that accepts a distance matrix. You could either write your own (not so difficult) or you could map the distance matrix to a Euclidean space using `cmdscale`.  Then use knn on the projected space.

Comment: alright, I tried to make all the columns to numeric values but it's still complain the same (no missing values allowed). Anyway thanks for guidance.

Comment: after the principal coordinates transformation by `cmdscale`, would it make sense to perform a PCA as the distance matrix maybe very large?

Comment: PCA is for reducing the number of dimensions and cmdscale will already have done that. The second argument to `cmdscale` (k) allows you to choose how many dimensions you want. The distance matrix will still be large because the number of instances (points) will be large.

Comment: Great, that is very useful! Didn't know about the implicit dimension reduction...

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your mistake is: data_train <-data[1:25000,]

You are including your header that you have not normalized. I was able to reproduce the same error. But when I changed to data_train <-data[2:25000,] it ran fine.