# R convert vector to number reference

Tags: r

I need to convert vector to numeric strings. I've tried the solutions in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30058362/r-convert-from-categorical-to-numeric-for-knn) but I get an error message

For example with this dataset:

```
v1 <- rep(c('a','b'),3)
v2 <- rep(c('c','d','e'),2)
vdf <- data.frame(v1, v2)

sapply(vdf, class)
      v1       v2 
"factor" "factor" 

sapply(vdf, mode) #I'm not sure why the mode shows as numeric as the value is a charecter
       v1        v2 
"numeric" "numeric"
```

I want to transform so that for each column I reference each of the vectors as 1,2,3,... like:

```
v1c <- rep(c(1,2),3)
v2c <- rep(c(1,2,3),2)
vdfc <- data.frame(v1c, v2c)

sapply(vdfc, class)
      v1c       v2c 
"numeric" "numeric" 
     sapply(vdfc, mode)
      v1c       v2c 
"numeric" "numeric"
```

Note that I have some columns with different number of vectors

When I try to convert it with the solution from Dieter Menne I get and error message:

```
df$iv1 = as.integer(df$v1) 
df$iv1 = as.integer(as.factor(df$v1))

Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "iv1", value = integer(0)) : replacement has 0 rows, data has 10
```

Am I doing something wrong or is there a better way to convert the data?

Comment: `vdf[] <- lapply(vdf, as.integer)`

Comment: That works. Thanks Sotos

Comment: `vdf <- data.frame(v1, v2,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Sotos comments I've been able easily resolve this issue. As per his comment the solution that worked for me is

vdf[] <- lapply(vdf, as.integer)

This converts the whole dataframe in one go.

Hope it helps someone else